# How to replace 4 backslashes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this string that I'm getting from an API request...

```
It was quick and great ! And it\\\\'s customized
```

and I want to remove all 4 of those backslashes (that precede an apostrophe).

Here is the spot where the code lives...

```
reviews = reviews_response.json()
filtered_reviews = []
for key, review in reviews.items():
    comment = review.get('textcomments')
    comment = comment.replace(r"\\'", "'")
    if len(comment) > 30:
        filtered_reviews.append(review)
```

`comment` is [image]

In this particular example, as I step through it in PyCharm, the variable `comment` never changes after `replace()` is executed. I've tried these things with no success yet...

```
regex = re.compile(r"\\\\")
comment = "It was quick and great ! And it\\\\'s customized"
comment = regex.sub('', comment)
comment = re.sub(r"(\\){4}", '', comment)
comment = re.sub(r"\\\\\\\\'", '', comment)
comment = comment.replace('\\\\\\\\', "")
comment = comment.replace('\\\\\\\\\'', "")
comment = comment.replace('\\\\\'', "")
comment = comment.replace("\\\\", "")
```

I want it to look like this...

```
It was quick and great ! And it's customized
```

## Update

After figuring this out I had 2 main problems.

1. The main problem I had was PyCharm gave me the wrong value.  The actual value was `It was quick and great ! And it\\'s customized`
2. I was not saving the result of `comment` back into `review` before appending it to `filtered_reviews`

Thank you everyone for your comments and help.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried?

Comment: We need way more details. How are you getting the string? What's the EXACT code you used to try to remove it? How are you displaying the string?

Comment: Radical thought: Try not to escape the input N times so you don't get such a broken string.

Comment: `"""It was quick and great ! And it\\\\'s customized""".replace("\\",'')`

Comment: @Kay - I'm getting this from an API request :/

Comment: I ran your code and it produces exactly the output you want.

Comment: @Kevin - which one worked? I'll try it again

Comment: I don't know which line in particular is responsible. I just know when I copy-paste that entire block of code into a script, along with `import re` and `print(comment)`, it shows `It was quick and great ! And it's customized`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex, look for the apostrophe following the backslashes and replace the whole pattern with just an apostrophe:

```
In [1]: s = "It was quick and great ! And it\\\\'s customized"

In [2]: s.replace(r"\\'", "'")
Out[2]: "It was quick and great ! And it's customized"
```

Based on your repr output you don't have multiple backslashes you have 2:

```
Out[4]: u"It was quick and great ! And it\\'s customized"

In [5]: s.replace(r"\'","'")
Out[5]: u"It was quick and great ! And it's customized"
```

Comment: @Kay. I am not using a regex.

Comment: From the question I don't know if it's `"it\\\\'s"` or `"it\\\\\\\\'s"`, i.e. if OP posted the string repr or the string itself.

Comment: @Kay,  I doubt it is repr as if it were in single quotes the string would be invalid

Comment: Yes, but OP could have omitted the quotes of the output of repr. Not incredibly likely but not impossible.

Comment: @Kay, what I meant was there could never be a repr output like that using single quotes, you would either have five or 3, four would cause an error.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - See my updated question.  I tried this but the variable doesn't change in PyCharm when I step through it.

Comment: @Chad, did you do `s =  s.replace(r"\\'", "'")`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I did `comment = comment.replace(r"\\'", "'")`

Comment: @Chad, if the string is like you have in your question then this 100 percent works, add exactly what `print(repr(comment))` looks like using the original string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - `print(repr(comment))` shows `u"It was quick and great ! And it\\'s customized"`

Comment: @Chad, your pycharm output does not match up with the repr output, if you want to see what you actually have just print it, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

try regex if you want.

```
>>>import re
>>>re.sub(r'(\\\\)',r'',"""It was quick and great ! And it\\\\'s customized""")
>>>"It was quick and great ! And it's customized"
```